# firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged not dynamically updating

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying firebase with angular. In my home page i have Menu where few menu items will only shown to logged in user. Here is code for this

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-nav" ng-init="tab=1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"><a href ng-click="tab=1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in">Home</a></li>
        <li ng-show="user.authenticated" ng-class="{active:tab===2}" ><a href ng-click="tab=2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in">Add Member</a></li>
        <li ng-show="!user.authenticated" ng-class="{active:tab===3}"><a href ng-click="tab=3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-show="user.authenticated"> <a href ng-click="user.unauth()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have used firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged to assign true/false value to user.authenticated var. Here is code

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            $scope.user.authenticated =true;
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            $scope.user.authenticated =false;
        }
    });
```

Now my problem is it works fine but not dynamically updating $scope.user.authenticated. Only Changes when i clicked home or login menu again. I have used same trick with OLD firebase (.onAuth) it was working fine.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this event doesn't run the digest cicle. Try calling `$scope.$apply()` just after you altered the scope. Look at: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's indeed the answer @ItaloAyres. Abdul: the Firebase JavaScript SDK never automatically ran the AngularJS digest cycle. Most likely you were using AngularFire's `$onAuth()` before (note the extra `$` in there). If you use AngularFire 2.0 you will find a similarly named method that automatically informs AngularJS of the authentication state change.

Comment: Yes i was using onAuth of OLD firebase, not with $ in it, eg. ref.onAuth(function{authData){}. I had to inject $firebaseAuth to controller to use this. now i am unable to use it hence firebase error says new sdk to lesten authentication(this is not exact phase i get).

Comment: $scope.$apply() worked very fine thank you.